# How to click on a unique element using cypress if there are many elements available?

Tags: e2e-testing, cypress

I am trying to click on a unique element, but there are many same elements.
I am new in Cypress.

`document.querySelectorAll('md-input-container md-datepicker input')`

It has 2 elements, I want to choose one element,
[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A20yV.png)

Comment: The best way to select the element will depend on what your DOM tree looks like. Please post the applicable HTML for your application.

Answer (score 2):

First, may I recommend trying to adopt the point of view of the user. In your test case, how will the user know what element to click ? Is it in a particular container, or next to an item of interest, or at a specific index in a collection of item, ... ?  Then try to implement the same logic in Cypress.

Example of narrowing down the search gradually:

```js
cy.contains('div', 'content of interest')
  .find('md-input-container md-datepicker input')
  .click();
```

Example of getting the element at a specific index in a collection:

```js
cy.get('md-input-container md-datepicker input')
  .eq(1)
  .click();
```

Example of locating by a sibling:

```js
cy.contains('div', 'element of interest')
  .parent()
  .find('md-input-container md-datepicker input')
  .click();
```

Comment: yeah, i got that ,i missed "eq()"